# Cant get EditText value from custom listView

Tags: android, listview

Excuse me, but i somehow cant post comments for the answers, so i have to write my own here

I need to get String data from custom ListView (consist of EditText and ImageView).
Here is my code:

1. First, i declare my own copy of ArrayList

   `private ArrayList<EditText> m_edit = null;`
2. Second, i initialize it inside onCreate method of my Activity

   `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...

       m_edit = new ArrayList<EditText>();
   ...`
3. Third, i fill my ArrayList with EditText copies and then add them to ListView using ArrayAdapter

   ```
   fieldAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {
       public void onClick(View view){
           EditText et = new EditText(AddCategory.this);    
           m_edit.add(et);
           m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
           }
       });
   ```
4. Fourth, i want to get EditText value for any item in my custom ListView. So i do something like this:

   ```
               for (int i = 0;i<m_edit.size();i++){
               _string = m_edit.get(i).getText().toString();
               }
   ```

And there is problem: result is always ""

What am i doing wrong?

#### My class source code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AddCategory extends Activity {

private ArrayList<EditText> m_edit = null;
private EditAdapter m_adapter;
private EditText categoryName;
private MyDbAdapter dbAdapter;
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);              
    setContentView(R.layout.addcategory);

    final Button categoryAddButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CategoryAddButton);   
    final Button fieldAddButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.FieldAddButton);
    final ListView fieldList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.CategoryFieldList);

    categoryName  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.CategoryNameEdit);        
    m_edit = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    this.m_adapter = new EditAdapter (this, R.layout.categoryfieldlayout, m_edit);     
    fieldList.setAdapter(m_adapter);
    dbAdapter = new MyDbAdapter(this);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    dbAdapter.open();

    fieldAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view){
            EditText et = new EditText(AddCategory.this);    
            m_edit.add(et);
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
            }
        });      

    categoryAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view){
            int duration;
            String error;
            long categoryID;
            ;
            int errCount = 0;
            if (!categoryName.getText().toString().equals("")){

                for (int i = 0;i<m_edit.size();i++){
                    if (m_edit.get(i).getText().toString().equals("")){
                        errCount++;
                    }
                }

                if (errCount != 0){
                    GroupItem group = new GroupItem(categoryName.getText().toString());
                    categoryID = dbAdapter.insertGroup(group);                  
                    for (int i = 0;i<m_edit.size();i++){
                            FieldItem field = new FieldItem(m_edit.get(i).getText().toString());                        
                            duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            error = m_edit.get(i).getText().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(context, error, duration).show();                            
                    }                       
                }
                else{
                    duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    error = "Field cannot be empty";
                    Toast.makeText(context, error, duration).show();                        
                }
            }
            else{
                duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                error = "Name cannot be empty";
                Toast.makeText(context, error, duration).show();             
            }
        }
    });            



}

private class EditAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EditText>{
    private ArrayList <EditText> items;

    public EditAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<EditText> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.categoryfieldlayout, null);
            }
            EditText et = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.fieldEdit);
            return v;
        }


        }    
}
```

When i update (write some text) EditText field of my custom listView item, i think, m_edit dont update its content automaticaly. So the problem is, how to force that update

ps. sorry for my poor english

Comment: once you click fieldAddButton only you will get the editText value. BTW where you are calling that for loop.

Answer (score 1):

From the code below, I guess you are going wrong by getting text from an `ArrayList` and not your `EditText` field.

```
m_edit = new ArrayList<EditText>();
for (int i = 0;i<m_edit.size();i++) {
    _string = m_edit.get(i).getText().toString();
}
```

Simply set a `ListView onClickListener` and you will get the Edittext value for each listview item you click. In your case...

```
final ListView fieldList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.CategoryFieldList);

fieldList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()  {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
 int position, long id) {

 EditText et = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.fieldEdit);
 String myText = et.getText().toString();

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myText , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you provide you code snippets so get more idea what you are doing with edittext Arraylist.
From this i can see that you are adding edittext in arraylist and refreshing your listview. but did your listview refreshed with added edittext or not? Then that is the main problem with your code.

Comment: I've edit my post and add the hole source code. Hope it helps.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your source,

I think you are using listview and on button click you are trying to get edittext value. but how can you know that which position view is got selected from the listview.

I think there is some problem in what you are asking and what you doing. i think what you are doing is on single button click you try to get all edittext value.

Comment: what i need to do is to save all the editText values of my ListView in database table. For that, i tried to use ArrayList to store all the EditTexts from my ListView. And just read the data from it. But i have a problem: I dont know, how to update ArrayList if where is any changes in listView (e.g. user entered some text). Something like that. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are getting blank value because in your listview you have not edited it..you can do it something like  this.

Inside your adapter getview method put this code

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                list.get(position).edittext.setText(ed.getText().toString())
            }
        });
}
```

Hope this may help you.